# Windows 10 - Select Boot Device or Insert Boot Disc on Reboot- Sudden Issue after Previously Working

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, bios, hardware-failure

This is a rather perplexing issue that a friend of mine has run into.

His machine runs off a 480GB Sandisk SSD as the boot drive, with an ASRock Mobo, i5 6400, etc. Win10x64, with all the latest updates AFAIK. There is the one drive, with nothing else installed. It's about 3 months old.

He turned it off last night attempted to boot up again- it simply reads "Select Boot Device or Insert Boot Disc on Reboot" error (Roughly that terminology).

He then rebooted again and spammed F12 to get the the "Select Boot Device" menu- but the SSD does not show.

I have ran through the following:

- Checked All Sata/Sata Power Cables are plugged in correctly (They Are.)
- Rebooted again 2-3 times- Now Boots Straight to Bios
- Reset BIOS to optimised defaults
- Powered Down PC, Removed Power Cable and Left for 10 mins, then Turned Back On- Same Result
- I'm not sure yet if the BIOS can see the SSD.
- The System WILL boot from a Win10 OEM install disc.

Options in my mind:

- SSD is dead
- Cable is Dead
- Some esoteric option is somehow changed and needs to be switched back.

What is the next step? I'm confused because the very same machine was working about 6 1/2 hours previously.

Thank You!

Comment: SSD is likely dead. take it off and plug it into another PC to test.

Comment: @DavidDai I hope not :(

Comment: @DavidDai Confirmed- Is Dead- Not using Sandisk again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out as @David Dai said, the SSD was dead as a dodo. The SSD was only 2 1/2 Months old, so beware of Sandisk SSDs, people.

Now working with Samsung 850 EVO.